# How do I echo in PHP without carriage returns?

Tags: php, echo, carriage-return

Whenever I do an echo in PHP, I get two extra carriage returns. For example:

```
<?php
  echo 'abc';
?>
```

yields abc[cr][cr]. If I copy my script to a different server, I even get [cr]abc[cr][cr].

How do I force PHP to echo only my string 'abc' and not the carriage returns?

Comment: You could leave off the final `?>`. Does that help?

Comment: @Ja͢ck: Why would you ever leave out the final `?>`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I always leave it off, actually; it avoids a situation whereby a trailing new line messes things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to conclude that a server setting causes PHP to precede and follow all output with an arbitrary number of carriage returns. Of course, this is an error in the config files of the web host I'm working with. It shouldn't be like this.

Comment: I just had the same problem and had to shorten my loaded string by  one character on the right, which worked. This is especially important when loading a number variable, because converting a string with a carriage return into a number does not work very well.

Comment: This "answer" is not actually correct. There is no server setting that is causing this. I can only speak to my own experience that I had an extra line AFTER the ?> at the end of the PHP file. Extra lines before and after the <?php ?> will cause additional output if you are calling the .php file as a 'service' kind of thing ("posting" a function call to it).

Comment: @Charlie I checked with the hosting company, and they suggested it was the server itself. They also claimed they couldn't change it. It's a long time ago. I'm no longer having this kind of problems.

Answer (score 9):

`echo` doesn't append a `\n` in PHP.

You may want to drop the closing `?>` though, then you guarantee you won't have any trailing output.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but there are no characters before or after the php tags. Removing the closing tag doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Mark In that case, something else is happening that you haven't posted.

Comment: That's possible, but I wish I knew what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mark Post the exact contents of your file, if you haven't. Also check the source file with a hex editor to ensure the first characters are the start PHP tag `<?php` and nothing else before it. A quick and dirty test would be to try and set a header, if there has been unbuffered output, it will fail.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, I did all that and I am sure that my file is clean. It must be a server issue, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: @Mark Look for server directives for prepending/appending files (Apache has one).

Answer (score 4):

Delete the two carriage returns after the `?>` (or remove the `?>`)

Answer (score 1):

`echo` by default does not have carriage return.

Unexpected empty space or lines are mostly caused by the script usage. If your process will be on a single line, then also do use a single line in script side. As for this example; `

On a different topic as a tip, even for more convenient things, you can do so by for simple `if`/`else` statements using [conditional statements](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Consider following example:
`<?php echo ($foo == "bar") ? "Foo was bar." : "Foo wasn't bar."; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

PHP scripts are natively placed in HTML files, and thus white space sensitive. This means any white space surrounding your  tags will be visible on screen. As you would want it to be as it could be mid-paragraph!

As the other answers suggest, either clear the new line returns surrounding your tags, or you can cheat remove the ending line breaks by tricking the PHP interpreter - by leaving off the final "?>" tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware of it and there is no trailing white space in my PHP files in this case. I think it is a server issue.